# Error: `'(@lvalue String) -> Text' is not convertible to '(String) -> Text'` in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Occasionally, when using `Text(_:)` in SwiftUI, I get the error `'(@lvalue String) -> Text' is not convertible to '(String) -> Text'`. This happens completely randomly, and is independent of the SwiftUI View or the contents of the text. It occasionally fixes itself, other times I have to restart my computer, other times I have to make a new SwiftUI file. So I'm wondering if this error actually means anything or if it's just a beta bug? Thanks.

**Note**: I am not including any other code as this happens in *any* SwiftUI file regardless of any other code. It is completely dependent on `Text`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error occurs if you have any item in a stack that has the wrong type, i.e. a type that is not convertible to String. The same error can occurs in the code below:

```
Text("Hello world")
Text(100)
```

The strange part is that the error occurs on the first row, even though it is the second row that fixes it. I would verify that you are only using strings in all your Text() to see if that helps.

EDIT: Apparently it can happen no matter what error occurs in the body. It seem that the error occurs on the first item in the body if anything is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I found that errors in SwiftUI are a bit strange now, i almost never pointed to right error, so check you code to find error somewhere, it could be something else, not only the line that xcode tells you.